# gherkin.lexer.LexingError: Lexing error on line 1

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

When I run my first test file with Cucumber I got this exception How to solve this?

```
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Error parsing feature file D:/intalled/CucumberConcepts/src/cucumber/features/myfeature.feature
at cucumber.runtime.FeatureBuilder.parse(FeatureBuilder.java:123)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:52)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:33)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:143)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:107)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:26)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Caused by: gherkin.lexer.LexingError: Lexing error on line 1: 'Feature : Proof of concept that my framework works

### This is my test file

```
Feature : Proof of concept that my framework works

Scenario Outline : My first Test
  Given this is my first test
  When This is my second step
  Then This is the final step
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do a couple of things: A) remove the spaces in `Feature :` and `Scenario Outline :` keywords; and B) change the Scenario Outline to Scenario (or add the missing examples for the outline).

If you run this feature:

```
Feature: Proof of concept that my framework works

Scenario: My first Test
  Given this is my first test
  When This is my second step
  Then This is the final step
```

Then cucumber will output the to-be-completed step definitions:

```
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given(/^this is my first test$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

When(/^This is my second step$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

Then(/^This is the final step$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

Comment: yp.that was the problem.thnx a lot @orde

Comment: A space between Scenario and : was the problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's a Gherkin Syntax Error : You can't have space between Keywords and Colon.

---

Actual = Feature :
Expected = Feature:

Actual =  Scenario Outline :
Expected =  Scenario Outline:

---

Scenario Outline: will always be used with Examples,

Now When to  Use **Scenario Outline:** and when to use **Scenario:** ?

**Scenario Outline:**

This is used when you have to test the same screen, with multiple sets of data

**Scenario:**

This is used when you have to test one scenario with one set of data or No data

**In your Case:**

You are testing feature with no data set. So you Should use Scenario instead of Scenario Outline.

Expected Feature:

```
Feature: Proof of concept that my framework works

Scenario: My first Test
  Given this is my first test
  When This is my second step
  Then This is the final step
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to addon as the cause of the error is not only the things mentioned by orde.

```
Feature: Proof of concept that my framework works

Scenario: My first Test
  Given this is my first test
  When This is my second step
  THEN This is the final step
```

Check that the "Then" keyword is all caps which is supposed to be in proper Syntactical manner. This damn sure leads to the lexical error.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the spaces in the feature file.
Ex: for Scenario check with the colon and for Given, When and Then there shouldn't be colon and more spaces.

Ex:
Scenario:Check with the spaces here
Given this is my given
When this is my when
Then this is my then

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).